# Is it possible to refer to the actions defined in a different launch?

Tags: ros2, roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'd like to know whether it's possible to refer to the actions defined in launch A, from launch B.

For example, considering the case of:

- start publisher after 5 seconds wait
- launch subscriber after publisher started

`pubsub.launch.py`

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import RegisterEventHandler
from launch.actions.timer_action import TimerAction
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessStart
from launch_ros.actions import Node


def generate_launch_description():
    publisher = Node(
        package="examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher",
        executable="publisher_lambda",
        output="screen",
    )

    launch_publisher_after_timer = TimerAction(period=5.0, actions=[publisher])

    subscriber = Node(
        package="examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber",
        executable="subscriber_lambda",
        output="screen",
    )

    subscriber_handler = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=publisher,
            on_start=[
                subscriber,
            ],
        )
    )

    return LaunchDescription([launch_publisher_after_timer, subscriber_handler])
```

This of course works as expected.
However, if I split this into two launch files, sub.launch.py doesn't work correctly. (I know my usage is wrong.)

`pub.launch.py`(imports are omitted)

```
def generate_launch_description():
    publisher = Node(
        package="examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher",
        executable="publisher_lambda",
        output="screen",
    )

    launch_publisher_after_timer = TimerAction(period=5.0, actions=[publisher])

    return LaunchDescription([launch_publisher_after_timer])
```

`sub.launch.py`(imports are omitted)

```
def generate_launch_description():
    publisher = Node(
        package="examples_rclcpp_minimal_publisher",
        executable="publisher_lambda",
        output="screen",
    )

    subscriber = Node(
        package="examples_rclcpp_minimal_subscriber",
        executable="subscriber_lambda",
        output="screen",
    )

    subscriber_handler = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessStart(
            target_action=publisher,
            on_start=[
                subscriber,
            ],
        )
    )

    return LaunchDescription([subscriber_handler])
```

`pubsub.launch.xml`

```
<launch>
  <include file="./pub.launch.py"/>
  <include file="./sub.launch.py"/>
</launch>
```

So my question is, can I use `publisher` Node defined in `pub.launch.py` as `target_action` in `sub.launch.py`?
I guess it's possible if there is a method to iterate all actions defined in other launch files and then filter by name.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375384/is-it-possible-to-refer-to-the-actions-defined-in-a-different-launch?/) by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on ROS Answers with karma: 307 on 2021-04-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible, but not with `OnProcessStart`.

`OnProcessStart` is syntactic sugar. An event handler [bound to the `ProcessStarted` event](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/b59bb6b88b40eaa82870542d93bdfb1a033d05c3/launch/launch/event_handlers/on_process_start.py#L58-L65) for convenience. [Generic event handlers](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/b59bb6b88b40eaa82870542d93bdfb1a033d05c3/launch/launch/event_handler.py#L31-L41) take an arbitrary callable to match events. So you can technically filter and listen to any kind of event you may want. For process events, there's even [a handful of convenient matchers](https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch/launch/events/process/process_matchers.py) you can use.

---

Originally posted by [hidmic](https://answers.ros.org/users/24051/hidmic/) with karma: 121 on 2021-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kenji Miyake](https://answers.ros.org/users/44068/kenji-miyake/) on 2021-04-05**:
Thank you, I'll try it!